# Setting PyMongo at PythonAnyWhere.com

Tags: python, django, mongodb, pymongo, pythonanywhere

I have deployed my django project on python anywhere but i am getting

> ServerSelectionTimeoutError at /register/
>   Got opcode 1684095520 but expected 1

my client setup for pymongo in views.py

```
client = MongoClient('localhost',80)
users_current_db= client.datab
```

Need help on this, Thanks in advance

Comment: MongoDB is likely not on `localhost` unless you could specifically install it there, and I don't think you can, or did. That needs to point to the address where MongoDB actually is. Perhaps you should be reading the PythonAnywhere.com forums - [Does Pythonanywhere have mongodb?](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/254/)

Comment: Thanx for the reply.. So it is not possible with pythonanywhere as it limits to mysql and postgre...How about using external mongodb like mlab and adding in the client here??

Comment: Well there are several entries in the forum about using "mlab" or other service, which is why I pointed you there. This really was not the place to ask anyway.

Comment: @NeilLunn Thanx